# Refresh dialog and its contents after submission

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuetify.js

I am using `v-dialog` to add some contents to the database. The fields are validated with `:rules` as below:

**Template:**

```
<v-text-field label="Title" v-model="title" prepend-icon="folder" :rules="inputRules"></v-text-field>
...
```

**Script:**

```
inputRules: [
    v => (v && v.length >= 1) || "Kindly enter a value for this field"
  ],
```

but after submitting the form and re-opening it again, the inputRules are still validating:

[image]

How can I refresh the form contents again or the dialog?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assign the whole of the form reference using [refs](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/api/#ref) attribute. Then after submission of the form clear the contents

```
this.$refs.resetValidation()
```

Answer (score 0):

Try the option to set `success` props ([API](https://vuetifyjs.com/en/components/text-fields#api)) to `true` after submitting the form. Or like a workaround, use some flag in your validators (`inputRules`) that will know if the form already submitted or no